# What's the best way to selectively render rails partials based on the page loading it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, partials

For example, all pages need my Footer partial, but the home-page has a couple words that need to be different, and Page Y has one minor alteration too.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the controller and action name:

```
<% if controller.controller_name == 'Projects' && controller.action_name == 'index' %>
<p>Alternate content</p>
<% end %>
```

Alternatively, you could pass in a different local variables to the partial from the page(s) in question:

```
<%= render 'my_partial', :do_something_wierd => true %>
```

then, in 'my_partial':

```
<% if do_something_wierd %>
<p>Alternate content</p>
<% end %>
```